# Minimum input for JSON parse

Tags: ruby, json

I am deserializing strings using `JSON.parse`. Most of the time, I have a contentful object serialized into a string, and `JSON.parse` works on that string, but in some cases, I want to send a minimum input to `JSON.parse`, whose result will just be thrown away. When I send `""` like: `JSON.parse("")`, it returns an error: `unexpected token at '""'`. What is the restriction of JSON specification that I am violating, and what alternative minimum string can I send to `JSON.parse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the JSON specification that Musa provided a link to, one minimum object that can be stringified and sent to JSON seems to be:

```
[null]
```

or something like that. Or, in the stringified form, it will be:

```
"[null]"
```

Comment: There is no `null` in Ruby, but you can use `[nil]` to get the equivalent JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I would send `null` as this represents "nothing".

```
require 'json'

nil.to_json
#=> "null"
```